# Creating a Nodejs commandline buffer to use within bash

Tags: node.js, bash

I am trying to create a program in nodejs that can be used as a replacement for mbuffer within linux.

right now, i can do this using mbuffer..

```
 echo "test" | mbuffer -m 50k | cat
```

I tried this...

```
const buf = Buffer.from('hello world', 'ascii');

console.log(buf.toString('hex'));
```

but how do I make it work so that I can use it like this...

```
cat "test" | nodejs mybuffer.js -m 50k | cat
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to read from [stdin](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin) and write to [stdout](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout), rather than using `console.log()`.